# Networking an external hard drive

Tags: network, external-disk

I want to buy a Seagate Backup Plus Desktop 4TB Thunderbolt drive, but I was wondering if it is possible to connect my external hard drive to a network. There are two options which might help:

1. we have a server, is it possible that I connect my external hard drive through my own macbook to the server that others could have access to it?
2. I might be able to construct a network and give access to the other computers to store their data on my external hard drive.

Comment: Why not just buy more disks for the server? Why do you need it for your portable?

Answer (score 1):

Many modern routers offer the ability to connect a hard disk directly to the router and make it visible on the network.  That might be another option to explore.

Comment: Such as Airport Extreme base station.

Answer (score 0):

Since OS X can share files like a server, most people just turn on File Sharing when their Mac has files it needs to share and then plug the drive into the server for when the Mac is away from the network.